# Symfony form with several inputs text type to fill array property of entity object

Tags: php, arrays, forms, symfony, input

I need to render a Symfony form to add entity object with his properties in the database. On of those properties is an array.

I want to display in the twig view several inputs text type field to fill this array. So i tried this following the doc but it doesn't display anything.

```php
$builder
->add('tracklist', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => TextType::class,
                'entry_options' => [
                    'attr' => ['class' => 'fs-1 text-center text-uppercase']
                ]
            ])
```

I have looked for answers a lot everywhere but nothing worked. I do something wrong and can't figure out what.

I'm not arrived at this point but at the end my point is to use some javascript to display an additional input text type each time the one before is filled. All those inputs will fill the array in the database. This is to add a tracklist for discs so I never know how many inputs i'll need.

Thanks for the help guys !

**// EDIT**

OK after multiples tries and fails. I finally did it without using Symfony. It's much more simple for what I need.

Here is the template part

```html
<p>TRACKLIST</p>
<div id="tracklist_container">
   <label for="tracks">TRACK 1</label>
   <input type="text" name="tracks[]" id="tracks">
</div>

<button id="tracklist-button">ADD A TRACK</button>
```

The JS part

```js
let tracklistContainer = document.querySelector('#tracklist_container')
let label = tracklistContainer.querySelector('label')
let input = tracklistContainer.querySelector('input')
let addButton = document.querySelector('#tracklist-button')
let i = 1

addButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    i++
    
    labelClone = label.cloneNode(true)
    inputClone = input.cloneNode(true)

    labelClone.textContent = "TRACK" + i
    inputClone.value = ""

    tracklistContainer.appendChild(labelClone)
    tracklistContainer.appendChild(inputClone)
})
```

And the PHP Controller part

```php
$safeTracks = array_map('trim', array_map('strip_tags', $_POST['tracks']));

$disc->setTracklist($safeTracks);
```

I get what I needed that way !

Comment: Create a new form type with all your text fields 
making the `data_class = null` then point your `entry_type` of the collection to that, eg. `entry_type => MyArrayFormType::class`.

Comment: @Bossman Thanks for the help, It still not working. I posted an answer to show you the code.

Comment: You should edit your post instead of posting an answer. The `data_class` doesn't go in your inputs, it goes in the `configureOptions` of the form class..

Comment: Ok I did it, still not working..
`$resolver->setDefaults(['data_class' => null])`

Comment: Unfortunately i can't help you with "*still not working*". Try and edit your post with the error you're getting or if the error message has changed etc..

Comment: I don't have any error message since the first try. The Tracklist form is just not displaying on the page.  And it's the same with the thing i changed with your help.

Comment: *not displaying on the page* - this is important. You have another issue. Okay, edit your post and post your controller code that is calling and rendering this form page..

Comment: Sorry if I'm not clear. It's only one form row who doesn't display, the CollectionType one, I have other ->add() that displays and works fine.

Comment: Ok I did it a complete other way without using Symfony, it looks way more simple that way. I edit the post

Comment: Hmm, was there any data in the `tracklist` (json) field? If it was empty then maybe thats why it was blank as there is nothing to show. You would then have the option `allow_add = true` on your collection. More on [Symfony Form Collections here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html).

Comment: No there wasn't, I begin to think that I wasn't using the right type.